# Не получается продублировать элемент односвязного списка

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

Дано указатель `Р1` на первый элемент не пустого списка. Продублировать в списке все элементы с четными значениями и нечетными номерами (Новые элементы добавлять перед существующими элементами с такими же значениями) Я сейчас написал немного кода где я хочу просто попробовать сделать дублирование одного элемента , но при компиляции консоль ничего не выводит . Вообще, я решил сделать просто дублирование после того как не получилось основное задание , хотел просто принцип роботы понять но и в том и в том случае консоль не выводит ничего

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
struct TNode {
    int data;
    struct TNode *next;
};
typedef struct TNode Node;
void CreateNode(Node** head, int d)
{
    Node *tmp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    tmp->data = d;
    tmp->next = (*head);
    (*head) = tmp;
}
void copy(Node** head)
{
    Node *tmp;
    Node *P1 = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    tmp = (*head);
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        if ((tmp->next->data)%2==0)
        {
            P1->next = tmp->next;
            tmp->next = P1;
            P1->data = P1->next->data;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
    Node *head = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        CreateNode(&head, i + 1);
    }
    copy(&head);
    while (head)
    {
        printf("%d\n", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Здесь вы бесконечно добавляете новый элемент не перед (как пишете в тексте условия задачи), а после последнего элемента. В цикле берете указатель на только что добавленный элемент, обнаруживаете, что он последний, копируете и ... все повторяется. Если хотите добавлять перед, то анализируйте не содержимое по `tmp`, а содержимое элемента по `tmp->next`

Comment: Я изменил код и как вы говорили пробовал анализировать через tmp->next ну и добавил условие (%2==0) Так оно все равно не хочет компилировать . Я в paint пошагово рисую что я должен соединять. (Мой прошлый код как раз и был для того чтобы добавить в конец после tmp элемент и я , чтобы не допустить цикличность специально добавил tmp=tmp->next оно не работало и позже заменил на tmp=NULL чтобы выйти из цикла(Так-же не работало)).

Comment: То-есть на счет прошлого кода я согласен там действительно была цикличность (не уследил) после я решил изменить условие (добавление n элемента перед тем , который подходит под условие) но консоль так же ничего не выводит , не могу понять почему

Comment: **1)** перед тем, как проверять `(tmp->next->data)%2==0` надо проверить, что `tmp->next` не 0, т.е. `if (tmp->next && (tmp->next->data)%2==0) { ...`    /  **2)** P1 надо выделять для каждого, т.е. `Node *P1 = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));` надо перенести внутрь if-a  / **3)** Новый `tmp = tmp->next` надо брать 2 раза -- внутри if-а  и после него `if (...) { .... tmp = P1->next;} else tmp = tmp->next;` / **4)** не ленитесь вставлять отладочную печать по всему своему коду (или пользуйтесь отладчиком)

Comment: Все спасибо вам огромное , все прекрасно работает 2)это я понял, 3) это тоже 4) Не знаю что это такое ,если честно (обязательно ознакомлюсь), спасибо за совет! Только вот 1) что значит tmp->next%2==0? не понимаю , это ж ведь адрес на структуру а как структура целая может делиться на 2 ?Еще раз спасибо вам

Comment: Если я где-то написал `tmp->next%2==0`, то это ошибка, конечно, я имел в виду `tmp->next->data % 2 == 0`

Comment: Очень странно т.к. с вашей "ошибкой" оно работает `(tmp->next && (tmp->next->data)%2==0)` возможно оно проверяет существует ли следующий элемент т.е. `tmp->next!=NULL`

Comment: Естественно, проверка `tmp->next && ` это не ошибка. Да, это сокращенная запись `tmp->next != NULL`

Comment: Спасибо вам !!!